# Is "dry" used as an adjective or verb in this sentence?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> Over the next day or so, London and the area around Kent can expect a
> couple of isolated showers, but mostly **dry** through until Thursday.

from https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/skills/listening/b1-listening/weather-forecast

If it is adjective, I think it should be: but **they are** mostly dry through until Thursday.  **they are** should not be omitted.

If it is a verb, the meaning feels strange.

By the way, is **dry through** together, or is **through until Thursday** together?

Comment: The weather forecast is spoken, and they try to use a "chatty" style. Here 'dry' is an adjective: "... but [it will be] mostly dry until Thursday". The speaker's "through until" is unnecessary duplication of a preposition. People make many small slips in grammar or syntax when speaking.

Comment: ...or "can expect a couple of isolated showers, but mostly dry **weather**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Dry is an adjective in this context

You are correct in that they are omitting the "to be" verb in this sentence (which should be conjugated "will be" not "they are"), but as this is a weather report, it is being omitted as everyone understands that they are always going to be describing what the weather will be like.

Additionally, **through until Thursday** is "together" in the sense that they mean throughout the time period from now until Thursday.

You are right to point out that this is a very lazy and poorly constructed sentence.